# Setting up .Net IBM.XMS client with SSL to KDPW

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq, xms

I am trying to connect to the testing environment in KDPW with NEt IBM.XMS

I received a Certificate from KDPW which is store in the Windows certificates store.

I create a KDB file from the received certificate.
KDB file is store in the directory C:\directory.
The name of the KDB file is nameOfKdbFile.kdb

when I try to connect I received error code:

IBM.XMS.XMSException: 'CWSMQ0006E: An exception was received during the call to the method ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection: CompCode: 2, Reason: 2538.
During execution of the specified method an exception was thrown by another component.

Can you help me?

Code:

```
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "ipAddress");
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, port);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, "channel");
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "queueManager");

cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_PEER_NAME, "peerName");
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SPEC, "cipherSpec");


cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_KEY_REPOSITORY, @"C:\directory\nameOfKdbFile");
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CLIENT_CERT_LABEL, "ibmwebspheremquserid");
```

Comment: Certificate is a property  (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q120650_.htm) and smaple code is shown here : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029500_.htm

Comment: What is _certificate label_ in the Windows store certificate? It is a friendly name?

Comment: See if this page helps : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q014220_.htm

Comment: `XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT` is managed mode and used the windows keystore.   Valid values for `XMSC.WMQ_SSL_KEY_REPOSITORY` are `*SYSTEM` or `*USER`.  If you want to use a kdb you would need to specify `XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT_UNMANAGED` for unmanaged mode.

Comment: Can you attempt a connectivity test to `ipAddress` on `port`?  2538 is MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE which is usually network level issue (not always).  Did you take into account my feedback above?

Comment: An unmanaged mode is working with kdb files. But Managed mode not, I try to set the friendly name of the certificate in the Windows store same as the certificate label in code but is not working. Some advice? `XMSC.WMQ_SSL_KEY_REPOSITORY` is set to `*USER`. With this setting is returned ErrorCode="CWSMQ0006" with CompCode : 2
Reason : 2059

Comment: What version of MQ are your dlls from?

Comment: 2059 is a more general error, in latest versions it should be replaced with a more specific error,  can you try at a later version?  Is the case matching on your friendly name and `XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CLIENT_CERT_LABEL`?

Comment: Yes I have the latest version and friend name and Cert_Label are equal.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what the latest version is? IBM MQ versions are in the format of 9.1.0.5 or 9.1.5, the former being a Long Term Support release the later a Continuous Delivery release.  The fact that you get a 2059 tells me that you are NOT at a level that has the fix and from what I can tell the last two fix packs of both 9.1 and 9.0 include this fix and 9.2 likely also includes it.  You can right click the dll in windows and find the version information.

Comment: I used WebSphereMqClient for .NET [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebSphereMqClient/8.0.0.7) version 8.0.0.7 because the KDPW used IBM Websphere MQ of version 8.0.0.3

Comment: I would suggest you go with 8.0.0.15, the later versions provided more detailed errors instead of 2059, so it is more helpful to understand what is wrong.  Also note that in SO if only one person has commented with you on a question or answer, then any reply from you will notify that person, but if as in this case there is more than one, it will only notify someone if you @tag the name, I had been checking back on this question but after a few days I stopped so didn't see your 9/29 update until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unmanaged mode is working with settings:

```
IConnectionFactory cf = factoryFactory.CreateConnectionFactory();


cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "ipAddress");
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, port);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, "channel");
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT_UNMANAGED);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "queueManager");

cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_PEER_NAME, "peerName");
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SPEC, "cipherSpec");

cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_KEY_REPOSITORY, @"C:\directory\nameOfKdbFile");
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CLIENT_CERT_LABEL, "ibmwebspheremquserid");
```

Kdbfile must has 3 parts: **.kdb**, **.rdb** and **.sth**